# Python eigenvectors: differences among numpy.linalg, scipy.linalg and scipy.sparse.linalg

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Scipy and Numpy have between them three different functions for finding eigenvectors for a given square matrix, these are:

1. [`numpy.linalg.eig(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html#numpy.linalg.eig)
2. [`scipy.linalg.eig(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html#scipy.linalg.eig), and
3. [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eig(A, k)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs)

Focusing specifically on the situation that all the optional arguments I've left off the last two are left at their defaults and that `a`/`A` is real-valued, I am curious about the differences among these three which are ambiguous from the documentation - especially:

- Why does (3) have a note that it can't find *all* eigenvectors?
- Why *must* the other two compute all solutions - why don't they take a `k` argument?
- (1) has a note saying that the eigenvalues are returned in no particular order; (3) has an optional argument to control the order. Does (2) make any guarantees about this?
- Does (3) assume that `A` is sparse? (mathematically speaking, rather than being represented as a scipy sparse matrix) Can it be inefficient, or even give wrong results, if this assumption doesn't hold?
- Are there other factors I should consider when choosing among these?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The special behaviour of the third one has to do with the [Lanczos algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm), which works very well with sparse matrices. The documentation of `scipy.sparse.linalg.eig` says it uses a wrapper for ARPACK, which in turn uses "the Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Method (IRAM) or, in the case of symmetric matrices, the corresponding variant of the Lanczos algorithm." [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK).

Now,  the Lanczos algorithm  has the property that it works better for large eigenvalues (in fact, it uses the maximum eigenvalue):

> In practice, this simple algorithm does not work very well for
>   computing very many of the eigenvectors because any round-off error
>   will tend to introduce slight components of the more significant
>   eigenvectors back into the computation, degrading the accuracy of the
>   computation. [(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm)

So, whereas the Lanczos algorithm is only an approximation, I guess the other two methods use algos to find the *exact* eigenvalues -- and seemingly all of them, which probably depends on the algorithms used, too.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an answer the non-routine specific part of your question:

In principle, the NumPy and SciPy `linalg()` routines should be the same. Both use LAPACK and BLAS routines internally. The implementation in `scipy.sparse` uses a specific algorithm that works well for sparse matrices (ie. a matrices with mostly zero entries). Do not use this if your matrix is dense.

Note that technically, the `eig()` in SciPy/NumPy be different implementations due to the fact that both packages can be built with different implementations of Lapack/BLAS. Common choices here would be standard Lapack/BLAS as available from netlib, [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/), Intel MKL or [OpenBLAS](http://www.der-schnorz.de/2012/06/optimized-linear-algebra-and-numpyscipy/).

Comment: One fairly significant difference between the two non-sparse implementations: `scipy.linalg.eig()` can simultaneously compute both left and right eigenvectors, while `numpy.linalg.eig()` can only compute right eigenvectors.