# Eigenvalue problems in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, eigenvector

I want to solve an eigenvalue problem using TensorFlow.
In particular, I have

```
e, v = tf.self_adjoint_eig(laplacian, name="eigendata")
eigenmap = v[:,1:4]
```

so I don't want to compute all eigenvectors.

In Matlab, I would use `eigs(laplacian,4,'sm')`

Looking at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/linalg_ops.py,
I see that `tf.self_adjoint_eig` calls `gen_linalg_ops._self_adjoint_eig_v2`.
However, I can't find `gen_linalg_ops` on Github or elsewhere.

Any advice on doing such linear algebra in TensorFlow, or is it best to go with other libraries in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB function EIG calculates all the eigenvectors. MATLAB function EIGS only calculates a selected number of the eigenvectors using precompiled https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK which implements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm There is no native MATLAB Lanczos code in MATLAB, most likely because the Lanczos algorithm is unavoidably unstable with respect to round-off errors, especially in single precision, making more stable implementations tricky and/or expensive.

An alternative to EIGS function is https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48-lobpcg-m that implements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOBPCG natively in MATLAB.

SciPy has an interface to ARPACK as well as the Python native implementation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lobpcg.html

Scikit uses ARPACK or LOBPCG for manifold spectral embedding
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.spectral_embedding.html and for spectral clustering http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html

TensorFlow now has a native implementation of Lanczos https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/solvers/python/ops/lanczos.py

Answer (score 2):

Current TensorFlow linalg implementations are single core and seem to be getting written from scratch, so it may take some time to match functionality of older libraries like Intel's Matrix Kernel Library.

You could do computation in MKL (available with conda version of scipy) and pass the values data between MKL and TensorFlow as numpy arrays. Since computation scales as O(n^3) for large enough matrices, the extra cost of data transfer will be negligible compared to computation.

For instance computing full SVD in MKL (which counter-intuitively, is [faster](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7339) than self-adjoint eig), I use following wrapper, which keeps in tf.Variable objects, and lets me switch between MKL and TensorFlow implementations

```
default_dtype = tf.float32
USE_MKL_SVD=True                   # Tensorflow vs MKL SVD

if USE_MKL_SVD:
  assert np.__config__.get_info("lapack_mkl_info"), "No MKL detected :("


class SvdWrapper:
  """Encapsulates variables needed to perform SVD of a TensorFlow target.
  Initialize: wrapper = SvdWrapper(tensorflow_var)
  Trigger SVD: wrapper.update_tf() or wrapper.update_scipy()
  Access result as TF vars: wrapper.s, wrapper.u, wrapper.v
  """

  def __init__(self, target, name):
    self.name = name
    self.target = target
    self.tf_svd = SvdTuple(tf.svd(target))

    self.init = SvdTuple(
      ones(target.shape[0], name=name+"_s_init"),
      Identity(target.shape[0], name=name+"_u_init"),
      Identity(target.shape[0], name=name+"_v_init")
    )

    assert self.tf_svd.s.shape == self.init.s.shape
    assert self.tf_svd.u.shape == self.init.u.shape
    assert self.tf_svd.v.shape == self.init.v.shape

    self.cached = SvdTuple(
      tf.Variable(self.init.s, name=name+"_s"),
      tf.Variable(self.init.u, name=name+"_u"),
      tf.Variable(self.init.v, name=name+"_v")
    )

    self.s = self.cached.s
    self.u = self.cached.u
    self.v = self.cached.v

    self.holder = SvdTuple(
      tf.placeholder(default_dtype, shape=self.cached.s.shape, name=name+"_s_holder"),
      tf.placeholder(default_dtype, shape=self.cached.u.shape, name=name+"_u_holder"),
      tf.placeholder(default_dtype, shape=self.cached.v.shape, name=name+"_v_holder")
    )

    self.update_tf_op = tf.group(
      self.cached.s.assign(self.tf_svd.s),
      self.cached.u.assign(self.tf_svd.u),
      self.cached.v.assign(self.tf_svd.v)
    )

    self.update_external_op = tf.group(
      self.cached.s.assign(self.holder.s),
      self.cached.u.assign(self.holder.u),
      self.cached.v.assign(self.holder.v)
    )

    self.init_ops = (self.s.initializer, self.u.initializer, self.v.initializer)


  def update(self):
    if USE_MKL_SVD:
      self.update_scipy()
    else:
      self.update_tf()

  def update_tf(self):
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    sess.run(self.update_tf_op)

  def update_scipy(self):
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    target0 = self.target.eval()
    # A=u.diag(s).v', singular vectors are columns
    # TODO: catch "ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs"
    u0, s0, vt0 = linalg.svd(target0)
    v0 = vt0.T
    #    v0 = vt0 # bug, makes loss increase, use for sanity checks
    feed_dict = {self.holder.u: u0,
                 self.holder.v: v0,
                 self.holder.s: s0}
    sess.run(self.update_external_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

And to use

```
covariance = data @ t(data)
svd = u.SvdWrapper(target=covariance)
sess.run(svd.init_ops)   # initialize to identity matrices
svd.update()             # update using latest value of covariance 
sess.run([svd.s, svd.u, svd.v])  # get values of factors
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find the `gen_linalg_ops.py` file in your local python installation, maybe in `~/.local/lib/` or something similar. There you can look for the directory `site-packages` which should contain a directory `tensorflow`. The `gen_linalg_ops.py` file is located in `python/ops`. The full path on my computer is `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_linalg_ops.py`, you might have something similar on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to solve it as a part of some bigger TF project or you just want to solve it for fun. In the second case, I would just use [numpy.linalg.eig](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).

I am confident that matlab's parameter which specify the number of eigenvalues just filters out unneeded eigenvalues after all of them were found. So it does not improve the computation time.

In this case you can just use [tf.self_adjoint_eig](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/self_adjoint_eig) from your TF program.

Comment: Thanks. (1) I'm including this in a larger method and I want to include this step as a "subblock" (i.e. within a namescope) of the TensorFlow graph, as it would be nice to visualize the whole process in Tensorboard.  (2) See my other comment.  In Matlab, eigs is *much* faster than doing a full computation of all eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

I found an Lanczos algorithm implementation with tensorflow [here](https://github.com/waleedka/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/solvers/python/ops/lanczos.py).

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I guess Matlab also calculates all the eigen vectors but then filters the no. of vectors needed.

The Numpy Linear algebra library is extremely well documented.
Please refer to the link below
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

Comment: Thanks, but Matlab uses the Lanczos algorithm, which is much faster when computing just a few eigenvectors and when the input matrix is very big (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm).   And thanks for the reference - it looks like there is a numpy/scipy-related post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083660/python-eigenvectors-differences-among-numpy-linalg-scipy-linalg-and-scipy-spar          ...However, my aim is to do this in TensorFlow if possible.